# Amazon S3 creating unique keys for every object

Tags: php, file, file-upload, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

My app users upload their files to one bucket. How can I ensure that each object in my S3 bucket has a unique key to prevent objects from being overwritten?

At the moment I'm encrypting filenames with a random string in my php script before sending the file to S3.

For the sake of the discussion let's suppose that the uploader finds a way to manipulate the filename on upload. He wants to replace all the images on my site with a picture of a [banana](http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fruits/512/Banana.png). What is a good way to prevent overwriting files in S3 if encryption fails?

Edit: I don't think versioning will work because I can't specify a version id in an image URL when displaying images from my bucket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you encrypting, or hashing?  If you are using md5 or sha1 hashes, an attacker could easily find a hash collision and make you slip on a banana skin.  If you are encrypting without a random initialization vector, an attacker might be able to deduce your key after uploading a few hundred files, and encryption is probably not the best approach. It is computationally expensive, difficult to implement, and you can get a safer mechanism for this job with less effort.

If you prepend a random string to each filename, using a reasonably reliable source of entropy, you shouldn’t have any issues, but you should check whether the file already exists anyway. Although coding a loop to check, using `S3::GetObject`, and generate a new random string might seem like a lot of effort for something that will almost never need to run, "almost never" means it has a high probability of happening eventually.

Comment: Thank you for responding! I'm encrypting to a random string. I guess checking if the file already exists is the best solution even if I make one extra S3 request. Or if I store all file info in a database I can check the db table with mysql.

Comment: As I mentioned above, encrypting the filename isn't the most effective solution. You could replace the name with random string, and store the mappings in your database. Look at `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`.

Comment: @TerenceJohnson, "almost never" can be "arbitrarily unlikely" by just adding more random bits.  Making an extra trip to S3 is going to hurt your service time.

Answer (score -1):

Checking for a file with that name before uploading it would work.

If the file already exists, re-randomize the file name, and try again.

Comment: A file with that name can be created after you've checked and before you've put your data.  That is, the two operations aren't in a transaction.